# How to wrap posix_memalign (to compile an old codebase on mac)?

Tags: c++, macos, malloc, posix

I am trying to compile a toolkit on mac. It has a reference to memalign function of malloc.h, but the only close function I could find for mac is posix_memalign. So I am trying to wrap posix_memalign to look like memalign.

I am a bit confused about how to do this (because of the void* and void** pointers):

The signature for posix_memalign is

```
int posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size);
```

and the signature for memalign is:

```
void *memalign(size_t blocksize, size_t bytes);
```

Any pointers much appreciated. ( Lame pun accidental! :)

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
void *memalign(size_t blocksize, size_t bytes) {
  void *result=0;
  posix_memalign(&result, blocksize, bytes);
  return result;
}
```

The `&result` will get you a `void**` to call `posix_memalign` with and then you can return the result as memalign did.

One point to note: this doesn't quite match the behaviour - memalign returns errors via `errno`, but `posix_memalign` returns them as an `int` and doesn't touch `errno`. You should see to it that errors are handled appropriately somehow still.

Comment: This wrapper made the function compile properly. But when running the toolkit I get a segfault. I am not sure if its because of this wrapper, or something else. I am investigating right now. If you are curious I am trying to compile the [SVDFeature toolkit](http://svdfeature.apexlab.org/wiki/images/8/85/Svdfeature-1.2.tar.gz) on osx lion.

Comment: @user1521607 posix_memalign requires the alignment to be a power of two and a multiple of sizeof(void*) but memalign only requires it is a power of two. I suspect that the alignment passed in is a power of two but less than sizeof(void*). Try rounding up to sizeof(void*) if this is the case. You also could assign errno with the result of posix_memalign.

Answer (score 0):

So handling errors correctly:

```
void *memalign(size_t blocksize, size_t bytes)
{
  void *m;
  errno = posix_memalign(&m, blocksize, bytes);
  return errno ? NULL : m;
}
```